# How do I allow users to supply a photo/image to be used instead of the grey/white silhouette?

Tags: plugins, posts

I am sure I am missing something very straightforward, but there seems to be no way for me to upload a photo for my profile or for a user profile the will be used in place of the placeholder white on grey silhouette that my theme displays.

I did Google for this, and I seem to get a bewildering array of possible plugins, but I would have thought that there was an easier way of doing this?

If I must install a plugin, what is the best one? (I realize that is a difficult question, but even getting it down to a shortlist would be nice!)

I am using Wordpress version 3.1.2 with the Twenty Ten theme version 1.2

I have the following plugins active:

Google Analytics for WordPress version 4.1
SyntaxHighlighter version 3.1.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A related question: [How to change user`s avatar?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7620/how-to-change-users-avatar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These images are called *Avatars*. By default, WordPress works with [the Gravatar service](http://www.gravatar.com/), which hosts your avatar on one central location so you don't have to upload it to every site you comment on. It is based on your e-mail address (you see it on action on this site too).

If you want to provide the functionality to load avatar images from your own site you will indeed need to load an extra plugin. Some popular plugins are:

- [Add Local Avatar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-local-avatar/)
- [Simple Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-local-avatars/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure why I could not find this info in the help for my site.

Comment: Yeah! It works. (Is that Flemish your blog is in?)